# How do I get the sibling of a tag after I use `:contains`?

Tags: ruby, css-selectors, nokogiri

I installed the `nokogiri` gem and made this method:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://example-page.com')
tag = 'div'
str = 'Some words in the div'
def tagContains(page, tag, str)
    return page.at(tag+':contains("'+str+'")').at('following-sibling::div')
end
```

But it crashes. I want to look up a `div` that contains the string, then select the `div` that comes after the `div` containing the string,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing a `)` at line one.

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.99mac.se/'))
tag = 'div'
str = 'Some words in the div'
def tagContains(page, tag, str)
  page.at(tag+':contains("'+str+'") > div')
end
```

Don't forget to post you error message next time.

Comment: When I run `p tagContains(page, 'div', 'Some words in the div')` I get this error: `unexpected ':' after ':' (Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError)`.

Comment: @Username Found the problem. I've updated the code accordingly.